# HP Proliant ML350 Gen9 doesn't start

Tags: hpe

We have a HP Proliant ML350 G9 server and yesterday it just stopped suddenly. Checked the power supply and it's stable 220 VAC. Server has two power supplies and both of them are lighting green. Also UID is blinking blue.
On the front panel all 4 LEDs are blinking simultaneously and server doesn't start.
There is only one green blinking led on the motherboard. Fans are also not working.

Im sure that power supplies are ok, what can be a problem then?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [HPE ProLiant ML350 Gen9 Server - LED Indicators](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=c04869958&docLocale=en_US) for interpreting the LEDs correctly. Count how many times the [power fault LEDs](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=c04869958&docLocale=en_US#N10119) blink to find the faulty component:

> 1. System board
> 2. Processor
> 3. Memory
> 4. Riser board PCIe slots
> 5. FlexibleLOM
> 6. Removable HPE Flexible Smart Arraycontroller/Smart SAS HBA controller
> 7. System board PCIe slots
> 8. Power backplane or storage backplane
> 9. Power supply

If you have warranty left, just open a support ticket with HPE and they will replace the component for you. Otherwise, replace or remove the component as applicable for you.

Comment: Power fault is continuously blinking without sequence

Comment: Reconnected supply and now there are 8 short and 1 long blink. Does it mean that problem is in power backplane or storage backplane?

Comment: As it has two power supplies, first try with just one and then with the other. If the problem gets solved, you have found your culprit, and can replace the power supply. Otherwise it might be the *power backplane or storage backplane*.

Comment: Tried to swap power supplies and run on only one, problem is still the same. Just to be sure: 8 short 1 long blink is fault number 8, correct?

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual,

> When all four LEDs described in this table flash simultaneously, a
> power fault has occurred. For more information, see "Front panel LED
> power fault codes ("Front panel LEDs power fault codes" on page 80)."

Comment: Thanks for your advice but there is no any sequence, all of them are continuously blinking.